# Animate 3 DIVs from right to left when page is loading.

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I am trying to animate 3 divs from right to left when page is loading.

My HTML is something like this -

```
<div id="Div1"></div>
<div id="Div2"></div>
<div id="Div3"></div>
```

I tried it using jQuery .animate but couldn't figure it out 100%. My problem is how it make to animate from right to left?

This is my jQuery -

```
var left = $('#Div1').offset().left;
var left = $('#Div2').offset().left;
var left = $('#Div3').offset().left;

$("#Div1").css({left:left}).animate({
    width: "200px",
    height: "200px",
    left: 0
  }, {
    duration: 3000,
    specialEasing: {
      width: "linear",
      height: "easeOutBounce"
    },
    complete: function() {
    }
  });

$("#Div2").css({left:left}).animate({
    width: "200px",
    height: "200px",
    left: 0
  }, {
    duration: 3000,
    specialEasing: {
      width: "linear",
      height: "easeOutBounce"
    },
    complete: function() {

    }
  });

$("#Div3").css({left:left}).animate({
    width: "200px",
    height: "200px",
    left: 0
  }, {
    duration: 3000,
    specialEasing: {
      width: "linear",
      height: "easeOutBounce"
    },
    complete: function() {

    }
  });
```

This is [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/XqqtN/3444/)

Answer (score 5):

Add `position: absolute;` and `right: -150px` to the `#Div1, #Div2, #Div3` css rule and remove `float: left`

http://jsfiddle.net/XqqtN/3446/

Here's another fiddle, with changing the `margin-left` values to be more like the 1 you examplified:  http://jsfiddle.net/XqqtN/3448/

And for easingeffects, just add an jQuery ui `easing` effect to the `left` and or `right` value.  Here's an `easeOutBack` ui effect to the `left` value and changed the duration to be a bit faster for this effect to look better:  http://jsfiddle.net/XqqtN/3449/

You may want to test with different effects and duration speeds for the exact look and feel you want, all jQuery UI effects are listed here:  http://api.jqueryui.com/easings/

You may also want to add a 1 or 2 second delay after the page is loaded to display the animation.  If so, just add `.delay(1000)` or however many milliseconds you want before the animation code (`.animate()`) gets ran.  This can also come in handy for helping to display the slide animation in the exact way you want it to come into play on the webpage.

Ok, so this is my last time playing with this, removed the height easing effect, as I think it was terrible anyways:  http://jsfiddle.net/XqqtN/3451/

Again, you will need to play with it to get it exactly how you want.  If this answers your question, please mark it as the answer.

## EDIT

Had more fun with it today and got it working so that it will center itself on the page as in the example URL you supplied, resizes itself to fit the content of the width accordingly (for this to work nicely, images are 512x512 pixels), placed headshot images in the circles, and hopefully this is exactly what you are after now:  http://jsfiddle.net/tT8pj/1/ and Full Screen result of the same exact code:  http://jsfiddle.net/tT8pj/1/embedded/result/

So, you can see how it resizes PERFECTLY and still stays in the middle not matter what the size of the screen.  If this answers your question, please mark it as the answer!  Though, if this hasn't answered your question, I don't know what will.

Cheers :)

Comment: But I need to make this alone side with other DIVs as a row. See my above fiddel my circle finally should be something like that.

Comment: This is close fiddle what I am looking for - http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/eV9Ms/ But Its a CSS3 solution. I am looking for a jquery solution.

Comment: Well, that's simple, just change the `margin-left` value of each of the divs accordingly...

Comment: Updated answer with 2nd jsfiddle changing margin-left values to resemble more like the fiddle you exemplified.

Comment: Thanks. My Dear friend can we add an animation to this something like this - http://builder.hypesalons.com/builder/users/2001070/index.html

Comment: You can add whatever kind of `easing` effect you want to the `left` value, here ya go, for an example:  http://jsfiddle.net/XqqtN/3449/